# Redis, wrong number of arguments for 'set' command node.js

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis, node-redis

I the simplest nodejs application that uses Redis to store sessions. I have downloaded and started reds-server on windows, but it bringsup the following error message

```
ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    at parseError (D:\Org\Projects\Up\Image metadata\Lab\Login with store\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (D:\Org\Projects\Up\Image metadata\Lab\Login with store\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:302:14)
```

My simple node.js express app is the following

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const redis = require("redis");
const connectRedis = require("connect-redis");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host:"localhost",
    port:6379
})


app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient}),
    secret:"shhhhh4",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: 5 * 30 * (24 * (1000 * 60 * 60))
    }
}));


app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    const sess = req.session;
    if (sess.username && sess.password) {
        if (sess.username) {
            res.write(`<h1>Welcome ${sess.username} </h1><br>`)
            res.write(
                `<h3>This is the Home page</h3>`
            );
            res.end('<a href=' + '/logout' + '>Click here to log out</a >')
        }
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html")
    }
});


app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const sess = req.session;
    const { username, password } = req.body
    sess.username = username
    sess.password = password
    console.log(req.body);
    // add username and password validation logic here if you want.If user is authenticated send the response as success
    res.end("success")
});
```

what is the problem? I have installed the latest of those imported modules, but still get the error

I am using `Redis server version 2.4.5`
and redis and redis-connect `6.14.6`

Comment: What version of redis are you running?

Comment: @eol I am using `Redis server version 2.4.5` and redis and redis-connect `6.14.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to a newer version of redis as your version is rather outdated and does not support the given options of the set command, see this [github issue](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/164#issuecomment-151415083) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, I updated, and `npm connect-redis --version` and `npm redis --version` now give me 6.14.6 But the problem still persists. I get the same error

Comment: It worked when I updated the server application itself to 3.0.5

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - glad, you got it working :)